# Ways to pass 2 int values from a child process to parent

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, mfc

Let me explain my dilemma. One of my processes that runs in user-mode with elevated privileges needs to provide an ability to open a user file, and if possible, get an exit code from that process. I do not want to open that file directly from my elevated process, but instead to run it with lower privileges. For that I do the following:

1. Start my second "shim" process, using [CreateProcessAsUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx), with lowered privileges. That "shim" process runs under a logged in interactive user account.
2. The "shim" process in turn first calls [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) for the user file (hoping that it's a process.) If that fails, it then tries to call [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) that may or may not return the process handle. So, if I get the process handle for the child process, I call [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) and wait for it to become signaled, after which I call [GetExitCodeProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the exit code from the process.
3. After that the "shim" process immediately closes.

My dilemma is that I need to pass 2 `int` values back to my main executable -- one is the result of execution: for instance, `ran file OK`, or `failed to run file`, or `file was not a process`, etc. And the second `int`, which is the exit code from the process itself.

The question is how to do it in the least complicated way?

**EDIT:** Just an idea. What do you think? What if I use system registry to pass back one of the ints? I can use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Brand\AppName` key for that and name the value as the concatenation of the child proc ID and the child process' creation time obtained by calling [GetProcessTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx) API. And then delete that key when the parent receives a response from the child.

Comment: Are any of the values greater than 255 or 65535?  If not, you can pack both into a 32 bit value and just return one 32 bit value then unpack at the main executable.

Comment: An anonymous pipe? Where the write-end is connected to `stdout` of the child process? That probably the most simple to set up as well as use from the child process.

Comment: @cup: No, obviously an exit code is a 32-bit value and I cannot arbitrarily truncate it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Good idea. I've never used those anonymous pipes. What APIs do I need for that?

Comment: Any IPC can be used, like [memory mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) or [Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable: I thought about using memory mapped files, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be that easy to do when one process is elevated and another one is not. (I'll have an issue creating a `Global\` mapped file object.) Pipes may be the answer... thanks.

Comment: @c00000fd  IInspectable provides a link to the MSDN pipe reference. Creating a pipe will give you two handles, one for reading and one for writing. When create the child process (I assume you use `CreateProcess`?) set the `hStdOutput` member of the [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to the write-end, and after you created the process close the write end. Read from the read-end of the pipe using `ReadFile`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Would it be an issue if a parent process runs elevated, and with higher mandatory integrity level than the child process?

Comment: I'm honestly not that well-versed in the windows API so I don't know that. The pipe solution just seems like the easiest to me. There are many other [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods, but pipes seems like on of the easiest and safest.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yeah. Thanks anyway. I know your pipes approach would've worked under XP, but since Vista they added a lot of extra security checks for IPC so many previous methods don't work any more.

Comment: Does the parent process have a window? You could just use PostMessage.

Comment: I had the same idea as @cup What range of exit codes are you realistically expecting? Sometimes a good solution can be found by just being pragmatic. You don't have to arbitrarily truncate the 32-bit code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Yes, but there're several issues with it. 1) The higher integrity level of the parent won't let the message through. 2) I will need to synchronize receiving of that message with the wait function in my parent function. 3) (My somewhat biased opinion) -- messages are somewhat unreliable.

Comment: @meaning-matters: As I said, it can be in the range from 0 to `0xFFFFFFFF`. I cannot predict it. It's an arbitrary process.

Comment: Guys, first off, I appreciate your quick input. I just thought of something. I edited my OP. Would it be bad to use registry for that?

Comment: One problem I can see with the registry solution: if the delete either fails or does not happen, the next run may be reading the wrong values.  @JoachimPileborg solution seems like a viable one as long as the child creates the pipe.  That way, if the parent is elevated, it doesn't matter: it can still read the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The boost interprocess header library will solve this for you while having the advantage of being platform-independent.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_memory_pool